# Why does println! print different outputs for f32 and f64?

Tags: rust, floating-point, ieee-754

Given this code:

```rust
let a: f64 = 0.1 + 0.2;
let b: f32 = 0.1 + 0.2;
let c: f32 = 0.30000000000000004;
let d: f32 = 0.300000012;

println!("{}", a); // 0.30000000000000004
println!("{}", b); // 0.3
println!("{}", c); // 0.3
println!("{}", d); // 0.3
```

Why does Rust only print the full floating point value (`0.30000000000000004`) for `f64`?

I know that in memory, variables `a` and `b` will not be exactly equal to 0.3. But I can't understand why Rust prints as it is in memory for `f64`, but for `f32` it uses a different approach and only prints `0.3`.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect Rust is producing just enough digits to uniquely distinguish the floating-point values from the neighboring values representable in the type.

> ```
> let a: f64 = 0.1 + 0.2;
> ```

`0.1` and `0.2` are converted to the `f64` values 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 and
0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125. Adding these produces the `f64` value 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125 (that includes rounding the real-number-arithmetic result to the nearest value representable in `f64`).

The neighboring `f64` values are 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875 and 0.300000000000000099920072216264088638126850128173828125. Observe that converting “0.3” to `f64` would yield 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875, because this value is closer to 0.3 than 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125 is. Thus, when formatting 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125, we must produce “0.30000000000000004” to distinguish it.

> ```
> let b: f32 = 0.1 + 0.2;
> ```

Here the sum is rounded to the `f32` value 0.300000011920928955078125.

The neighboring `f32` values are 0.2999999821186065673828125 and 0.3000000417232513427734375. Observe that converting “0.3” to `f32` yields 0.300000011920928955078125 (the value we are printing), not 0.2999999821186065673828125, because 0.3 is closer to the former than to the latter. Thus, producing “0.3” suffices to distinguish 0.300000011920928955078125.

> ```rust
> let c: f32 = 0.30000000000000004;
> let d: f32 = 0.300000012;
> ```

These set `c` and `d` to the same `f32` value as `b`, so they get the same output.